# Why is my angle of 2 vectors function return NaN even though i follow the formula

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, nan, angle

I'm making a function that calculates the angle between 2 given vectors for my unity game using the dot product formula:

```
vector(a)*vector(b)=|vector(a)|*|vector(b)|*cos(the angle)
```

so I figured that the angle would equals

```
acos((vector(a)*vector(b))/(|vector(a)|*|vector(b)|))
```

Anyway here's my code:

```
float rotateAngle(Vector2 a,Vector2 b)
    {
        return Mathf.Acos((a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y) / ((Mathf.Sqrt(a.x * a.x + a.y * a.y)) * (Mathf.Sqrt(b.x * b.x + b.y * b.y)))) * (180 / Mathf.PI);
    }
```

But when i played it the console showed `NaN`. I've tried and reviewed the code and the formula but returned empty-handed.

Can someone help me? Thank you in advanced!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`float.NaN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.single.nan) is the result of undefined (for real numbers) mathematical operations such as `0 / 0` (note from the docs that `x / 0` where `x != 0` rather returns positive or negative infinity) or the square root of a negative value. As soon as one operant in an operation already is `NaN` then also the entire operation returns again `NaN`.

The second (square root of a negative value) can not happen here since you are using squared values so most probably  your vectors have a magnitude of `0`.

---

If you look at the [`Vector2` source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector2.cs) you will find their implementation of [`Vector2.Angle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Angle.html) or [`Vector2.SignedAngle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.SignedAngle.html) (which you should rather use btw as they are tested and way more efficient).

> ```
>     public static float Angle(Vector2 from, Vector2 to)
>     {
>         // sqrt(a) * sqrt(b) = sqrt(a * b) -- valid for real numbers
>         float denominator = (float)Math.Sqrt(from.sqrMagnitude * to.sqrMagnitude);
>         if (denominator < kEpsilonNormalSqrt)
>             return 0F;
>
>         float dot = Mathf.Clamp(Dot(from, to) / denominator, -1F, 1F);
>         return (float)Math.Acos(dot) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
>     }
>
>     // Returns the signed angle in degrees between /from/ and /to/. Always returns the smallest possible angle
>     public static float SignedAngle(Vector2 from, Vector2 to)
>     {
>         float unsigned_angle = Angle(from, to);
>         float sign = Mathf.Sign(from.x * to.y - from.y * to.x);
>         return unsigned_angle * sign;
>     }
> ```

There you will find that the first thing they check is

> ```
> float denominator = (float)Math.Sqrt(from.sqrMagnitude * to.sqrMagnitude);
> if (denominator < kEpsilonNormalSqrt)
>     return 0F;
> ```

which basically makes exactly sure that both given vectors have a "big enough" magnitude, in particular one that is not `0` ;)

---

Long story short: Don't reinvent the wheel and rather use already built-in [`Vector2.Angle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Angle.html) or [`Vector2.SignedAngle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.SignedAngle.html)

Comment: Actually I tried the Vector2.SignedAngle from the very start but it didn't work. I just rechecked it and turns out i got the vector from and to all messed up. Thanks so much for the detailed explanation:D Lesson learnt:)

Answer (score 2):

NaN are typically the result of invalid mathematical operations on floating point numbers. A common source is division by zero, so my guess would be that the vector is 0,0.

I would also recommend using the built in functions for computing the normalization, Length/Magnitude, Dot etc. that will make the code much easier to read, and the compiler should be fairly good at optimizing that kind of code. If you need to do any additional optimization, only do so after you have done some measurements.

Comment: Ahhhhh yes, that's the exact problem! 1 of my vectors is (0,0) so it messed up. Thanks a lot, i'll also look for these built-in functions:)